# Error React Developer Tools incluso despues de build

Tags: reactjs, dev-tools

Estoy realizando el desarrollo de una página, la cual me retorna en consola del navegador el siguiente mensaje.

> React Developer Tools: You are running an unrecognized installation of
> the React Developer Tools extension, which might conflict with other
> versions of the extension installed in your browser. Please make sure
> you only have a single version of the extension installed or enabled.
> If you are developing this extension locally, make sure to build the
> extension using the `yarn build:<browser>:local` command.

No se que código poner ya que llevo meses trabajando en dicha página y anteriormente no me salía el este mensaje..
Lo único nuevo que hice fue algunas instalaciones nuevas para usar **React Native**

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

If you are using react developer tools addons, then this type of alert will be appeared. So after uninstalling this, you can avoid this error. Otherwise, according to the alert you can install your react app with *yarn build

Comment: Thanks, but translate your answer into Spanish please

Comment: Si está utilizando "react developer tools addons", aparecerá este tipo de alerta. Entonces, después de desinstalar esto, puede evitar este error. De lo contrario, según la alerta puede instalar su "react app" con "yarn build"

Comment: Agradezco la traducción, no tuve mucho problema para leerla, pero la razón de solicitar que traduzcas es por que estamos en StackOverflow en español.

Comment: Con referente a lo que mencionas, lo ideal no es eliminar el complemento, ya que lo utilizo para realizar el seguimiento de algunos elementos durante el desarrollo con Reactjs, tampoco funciona usar `yarn build` o `npm run build` por que el problema persiste.